# accessExternalSchema is not recognized

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, jaxp

I am trying to generate Java classes using Maven from XSDs/WSDLs. I have declared all the XSDs in my POM file and using the XJC plugin. When I try to do a clean install, I see these two error messages show up.

```
[DEBUG] [SchemaGen]: May 02, 2019 5:49:09 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory allowExternalAccess
CONFIG: Property "http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema" is not supported by used JAXP implementation.
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalSchema' is not recognized.
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.setProperty(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.allowExternalAccess(XmlFactory.java:236)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:87)


[DEBUG] [SchemaGen]: May 02, 2019 5:49:09 PM com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory allowExternalDTDAccess
CONFIG: Property "http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD" is not supported by used JAXP implementation.
org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: Property 'http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD' is not recognized.
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.setProperty(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.allowExternalDTDAccess(XmlFactory.java:267)
        at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.parser.SchemaConstraintChecker.check(SchemaConstraintChecker.java:110)
```

I did all the necessary changes in the jaxp.propterties file in my JRE/lib folder. This is the content of the property file. I have stored it in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre\lib. That is what maven is using.

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
javax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all
```

Is this actually an error or can be ignored?

Comment: Are you behind some firewall or need a proxy ? Can you call the urls from the browser or curl them ?

Comment: I am in a corporate network. So yes to the firewall. And proxy is a yes too!

Comment: Do you setup your proxy settings in your ```settings.xml``` ?

Comment: Yes i have the proxy setup in the settings.xml, the usual way. Sorry cant paste it here as it says too long.

Comment: Do you got a multi module project? Maybe the jaxb plugin is corrupt removing the proxy settings as explained here https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin/issues/60 ?

Comment: Ok. I see... Do you mean just delete the repository folder and remove the proxy and try doing a build again?

Comment: No, first of all ist your project calling the jaxb plugin anytime before you reach your error ? Maybe some other xjc ? Seems like the plugin removes the proxy while this process temp.

Comment: Oh...No at this point of time I am trying to build the project in isolation, so I dont think XJC is called from anywhere else! But I will give what you did a try and report back!